# Fullcalendar - angular business hours not showing

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar-angular (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular) and the issue I am facing is that the business hours are not being showed.

I am using Angular 8.0

I even tried to make it work on the official demo, but without success:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo-5atcjy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
     {
       daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
       startTime: '08:00', // 8am
       endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
     },
     {
       daysOfWeek: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
       startTime: '10:00', // 10am
       endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
     }
   ],
```

The result I expect is to have these hours grayed out on the calendar.
Can someone please advise if this is an issue on fullcalendar side or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling like me,
the "binding" should not be done on the typescript (component side) but on the html side

```
<full-calendar #calendar [businessHours]="businessHours">
</full-calendar>
```

Comment: so the above code in your answer is for you actual code, not for the code on the official demo right?

Comment: Works as expected. I don't know why they have mentioned this in documentation.
Also for typescript, you can use component as below

`this.calendarComponent.getApi().setOption('businessHours', {});`